# Magento 2.4.6 - Set the sort of the attributes in a programmatically created configurable product by setUsedProductAttributeIds()

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm successfully import from a CSV file a massive number of SIMPLE products.
Than I created the CONFIGURABLE products and assigned the simples by

```
$configurableproduct_load->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$configurableproduct_load->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(258,267,178), $configurableproduct_load);
$configurableAttributesData = $configurableproduct_load->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurableproduct_load);
$configurableproduct_load->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

$configurableproduct_load->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);
$configurableproduct_load->save();
```

where 258, 267, 178 are the attributes id in the sort that I want.
However, Magento create the CONFIGURABLE product assigned to it the configuration in the ASCENDING order: 178,258,267. This always appens, with all combinations of attribute id.

[image: Frontend result]

How I can assign my own sorting?

Comment: Of course, array(258, 267, 178), is just a sample. But I always get the issue with the given array :/ the defined order is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1.Retrieve the configurable product attributes and their values:

```
$configurableAttributesData = $configurableproduct_load->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurableproduct_load);
```

2Modify the sorting order of the attributes in the **$configurableAttributesData** array based on your desired order. For example, if you want the order to be 258, 267, 178,

```
$newOrder = array(258, 267, 178);
usort($configurableAttributesData, function ($a, $b) use ($newOrder) {
    $posA = array_search($a['attribute_id'], $newOrder);
    $posB = array_search($b['attribute_id'], $newOrder);
    return $posA - $posB;
});
```

3.Set the updated configurable attributes data to the configurable product:

```
$configurableproduct_load->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
```

4.Save the configurable product to apply the changes:

```
 $configurableproduct_load->save();



By using the **usort** function and providing a custom comparison function, you can define your own sorting order based on the attribute IDs. The configurable attributes will be sorted according to the order specified in the **$newOrder** array.
```

Comment: No :/ unfortunely nothing changed.
Please, note also that the original sequenze of $attributeId given to first argument (array) of setUsedProductAttributeIds was as wished, but never assigned as aspected :/

Comment: In each my random check, Magento assign the attribute in "attribute_id" sort order ascending. Never seen nothing before 2.3.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution: to sort the attributes programmatically I set the key "position" of each attribute after created $configurableAttributesData

I hope this will be usefully for everyone ;)